# Unlocking voting on Stack Overflow

Tags: support

I got a notification saying I had unlocked voting for passing 15 reputation points, but I cannot vote and I only have 13 reputation points. Any ideas on what happened?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See [Incorrectly informed of gaining a privilege](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/224022/incorrectly-informed-of-gaining-a-privilege):

> We don't "revoke" privilege gain messages by design.

You reached 15 reputation and got a notification, then you lost some reputation and the privilege was revoked. The message itself is not removed, by design.

Comment: Well, it's not a bug, it's a feature ;)